# OpenCV4Android Native Method Not Found

Tags: java, android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

For my very first Android app, I am trying to create an app that stitches images together.  After getting the UI set up and doing a little research it seemed that OpenCV4Android was a good choice.  Unfortunately for me, the image stitching portion of OpenCV4Android requires that I use Android NDK.  I used [this youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RmPuwdxR1qs) in addition to my existing code in order to get set up.

The code from the tutorial works correctly inside my project, but when I try to use "Mat" or "Imgcodecs.imread(...)" inside the Java portion similar to [this example](https://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/12/21/panorama-app-on-android-using-stitching-module-opencv/) I get this error:

```
4-16 21:09:02.116 28450-28450/aaron.picstitch E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: aaron.picstitch, PID: 28450
  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:(III)J
  at org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat(Native Method)
  at org.opencv.core.Mat.<init>(Mat.java:37)
  at aaron.picstitch.CameraActivity.<init>(CameraActivity.java:46)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have been looking through similar stackoverflow questions and using something like

```
static {
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    // Handle initialization error
    }
}
```

seems to work for most people but it does not work for me.  I am looking for help with trying to make OpenCV objects (like "Mat") work inside my existing Java code if it is possible.

Others on similar stackoverflow questions also asked to see the gradle.build (module app), so here it is:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "aaron.picstitch"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    ndk {
        moduleName "MyLibrary"
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir "src/main/libs"
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile project(':openCVLibrary310')
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: how do you build **libMyLibrary.so** that should be found in **src/main/libs** folder?

Comment: @AlexCohn I created a tool for ndk-build (at ~1:02 of YouTube tutorial) and then used it on the jni folder (at ~7:33 of YouTube tutorial).  My values are the same except for the Program path.

Comment: Cool. Is the library actually built? Do you load it from your Java?

Comment: @AlexCohn Yes I believe so? I just followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTw_GIQNbD8) and the OpenCVLoader part still doesn't work

Comment: Actually it just started working.   My mistake was using two static{ } blocks, one for OpenCVLoader, and one for the NDK library.  I guess by not doing that, OpenCVLoader works.